# How do I check if a string only contains alphanumeric characters and dashes?

Tags: python, regex, string, alphanumeric

The string I'm testing can be matched with `[\w-]+`. Can I test if a string conforms to this in Python, instead of having a list of the disallowed characters and testing for that?

Comment: Without locale indication alphanumeric characters match only `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`, not `[\w]+`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want to test a string against a regular expression, use the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) library

```
import re
valid = re.match('^[\w-]+$', str) is not None
```

Answer (score 8):

Python has regex as well:

```
import re
if re.match('^[\w-]+$', s):
    ...
```

Or you could create a list of **allowed** characters:

```
from string import ascii_letters
if all(c in ascii_letters+'-' for c in s):
    ...
```

Comment: re.match('^[\w-]+$', s) return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern. Should be compared with None.

Comment: @Enor Why? Any match object will be truthy, None is the only possible falsy value.

Answer (score 8):

Without importing any module just using pure python, remove any none alpha, numeric except dashes.

```
string = '#Remove-*crap?-from-this-STRING-123$%'

filter_char = lambda char: char.isalnum() or char == '-'
filter(filter_char, string)

# This returns--> 'Remove-crap-from-this-STRING-123'
```

Or in one line:

```
''.join([c for c in string if c.isalnum() or c in ['-']])
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, you do not need regex or external packages to solve this.

Comment: Completely agree

Answer (score 1):

To test if the string contains *only* alphanumeric and dashes, I would use

```
import re
found_s = re.findall('^[\w-]+$', s)
valid = bool(found_s) and found_s[0] == s
```